# Angular 5 social login idpiframe_initialization_failed AWS Cloud 9

Tags: javascript, angular, google-oauth, angular5, google-signin

I am using npm `angular5-social-login` to login with Google. Error I am receiving is `idpiframe_initialization_failed` `Not a valid origin for the client: http://18.219.144.71:8080 has not been whitelisted for client ID my_client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com`

I have, however, added this URI to the whitelist as seen below:
[image]

The URI is coming from AWS Cloud9 instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears that you cannot use public IP addresses as the whitelisted domain. Still currently looking for a solution.

Comment: You should insert a domain name in the Javascript origin.
You may play with DNS, redirection or something like that to get over this.